# How to get a clean string with extension with preg_replace in php?

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

I'd like to convert this string

```
$text = "TEST#%_'JanE,.-_doc30)/||\.pdf$@!3)";
```

into a clean string like this

```
TEST_JanE_doc30.pdf
```

So, basically the preg_replace should be:

- change all non letter and number before the extension into a single underscore (_) for delimiter
- remove anything after the extension
- keep the file extension (in this case the .pdf, but it could be anything else)

Is this possible? This is my current preg_replace:

```
$text          = "TEST#%_'JanE,.-_doc30)/||\.pdf$@!3)";
$text_filter_1 = preg_replace('/[^.\d\w\.]+/', '_', $text);
$text_filter_2 = preg_replace('/\./', '_', $text_filter_1);
```

Comment: How do you know the `3` is not a valid part of the file extension?

Comment: no mp3 files i guess

Comment: @Nick its after the extension

Comment: @tim I'm open to any suggeston :)

Comment: @Shota both answers will work with mp3 (or similar) extensions.

Comment: Define `after the extension`  filenames can have `.`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working script, which uses several regex replacements to get the job done.  The most critical logic is the initial regex split on the following pattern:

```
(?=\.\w+)(?!.*\..*\.)
```

This says to split on the very last dot, which is assumed to be the extension of the file.  It leaves us with the following two components:

```
Array
(
    [0] => TEST#%_'JanE,.-_doc30)/||\
    [1] => .pdf$@!3)
)
```

The remainder of the script handles the filename by replacing all groups of non word characters with a single underscore placeholder.  Then, another regex retrieves the extension of the file by stripping off everything after `.pdf`.

```
$text = "TEST#%_'JanE,.-_doc30)/||\.pdf$@!3)";
$parts = preg_split ("/(?=\.\w+)(?!.*\..*\.)/", $text); 
$filename = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/', '_', $parts[0]);
$filename = preg_replace('/_$/', '', $filename);
$ext = preg_replace('/^(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+).*$/', '$1', $parts[1]);
print_r($parts);
$file = $filename . $ext;
echo $file;

TEST_JanE_doc30.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a 3-stage replace. Note I have assumed that the file extension is the alphanumeric characters immediately after the final period, any others (such as the `3` in your test data) are discarded.

```
$text = "TEST#%_'JanE,.-_doc30)/||\.pdf$@!3)";
$text = preg_replace(array('/[^\dA-Za-z]+(?=.*\.[^.]+$)/',
                           '/_\./', 
                           '/(\.[\dA-Za-z]+).*$/'),
                     array('_', 
                           '.',
                           '$1'),
                     $text);
echo $text;
```

The first regex replaces any sequence of non alphanumeric characters before the final period (determined with the positive lookahead `(?=.*\.[^.]+$)`) with a single `_`; The second replaces the `_.` sequence (if it exists after the first replacement) with a `.`, and the final removes any characters after the file extension.

Output:

```
TEST_JanE_doc30.pdf
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/UR3vT)